# where do I report bugs in font packages

Tags: fonts, math-mode

There are two font packages I like for great readability (letters are clearly distinguishable, and math fonts stands out from text since it is heavier a bit).  Unfortunately, they are buggy.

The first one, the one which I think gives the most readable math fonts is Boisik. I love its curly brace: very distinguishable from parentheses, brackets. Unfortunately, it has a problem with some small size fonts: it doesn't seem to have some of them in the 11pt and 12pt options to the class file, like article. Here is a small sample file

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage{boisik} 

\begin{document} 

$$
T^{ U_{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789}} \quad a \alpha
$$

\end{document}
```

When you compile (I have TeX Live 2012) the above, you won't get i,j,m,n,u.  You get the same problem with the 12pt option, but no problem with 10pt, that is, without option.  The above file also exhibits another problem (which seems to be common to other font packages as well), that the `a` and `\alpha` characters look almost the same.

Another package I have problem with is `gfsneohellenic`.  For me, it has the best textfonts.  But I cannot use the package in my work since in math mode the characters `a` and `\alpha` are exactly the same. Another problem with the package is that in subscripts it crams binary symbols with their surroundings.  In regular environment, binaries seem to be fine.  Here is a sample file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[default]{gfsneohellenic}

\begin{document}

$$
a = \alpha\qquad \sum_{n \le N}\qquad n \le N.
$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Oh, and note that `$$ .. $$` should not be used with LaTeX, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: Find the author of the packages by looking in the readme and the documentation and using your favorite search engine and sent them your bug report. E.g. a search for the gfs-font lead to this page: http://www.greekfontsociety.gr/pages/en_typefacestex.html

Answer (score 4):

The "Latin italic a" is identical to the "Greek italic alpha" also in the text font, so this seems deliberate. Perhaps an unfortunate choice, but not a bug.

You can correct "manually" this choice by using the "slanted a".

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[default]{gfsneohellenic}
\DeclareSymbolFont{slanted}{T1}{neohellenic}{m}{sl}
\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{slanted}{`a}

\begin{document}

The first Greek letter is \textit{alpha}.
\[
a = \alpha\sum_{n \le N} n \le N.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The example shows what I said about the italic "a". In the formula you see that a different "a" appears; not the usual italic shape, but there's no other way to distinguish it from an alpha.

As for the Boisik fonts, they are bitmap, so their extensive usage cannot be recommended. They're also not particularly interesting to me, but this is only my opinion.